# Is EM64T the same as VT-Enabled?

Tags: virtualization, terminology, dell-poweredge

I have here a Dell Poweredge 850 which I got from my old work, I just install windows 7 to test and see if everything is ok, I want to set it up as a linux ubuntu server using Virtualbox, and or vmware ESXi,

I read that this require VT Enabled in the bios, I cannot find this option except under CPU : EM64T

is this the same as VT Enable ?

Comment: http://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [EMT64T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Intel_64_implementations) refers to intel's implementation of the 64 bit extensions to the x86 architecture. VT-enabled refers to the processor/motherboard combo supporting the [VT-X extentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT-X#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29). There are also [VT-D extentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT-X#I.2FO_MMU_virtualization_.28AMD-Vi_and_VT-d.29) which are necessary for some VM software to have direct, or near direct access to hardware

You should be able to run virtualbox with no issues *unless* you want to run a 64 bit guest on a 32 bit host (in short, go for a 64 bit host os if you can). esxi dosen't mention vt-d [as a requirement](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003661) , but its a bit picky about supported hard disk controllers.

Your system dosen't have VT enabled, but running either option should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the same thing. EM64T simply means that it supports "long mode", or 64-bit memory addressing mode. Not all Intel CPUs support VT. What exact model is it? If your BIOS doesn't show it, it probably doesn't have it.